# Any difference between c_associated() and associated() for checking association?

Tags: pointers, fortran

In the following code, I am trying to check the association status of a C pointer (1) by using `c_associated()` directly to the C pointer, or (2) using `associated()` to the Fortran pointer obtained from `c_f_pointer()`.

```
module test_m
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none

contains

subroutine sub( cp )
    type(c_ptr) :: cp
    integer, pointer :: fp

    print *, "cp ? ", c_associated( cp )   !! Line 1

    call c_f_pointer( cp, fp )

    print *, "fp ? ", associated( fp )   !! Line 2
end subroutine

end module

program main
    use test_m
    implicit none
    type(c_ptr) :: cp
    integer, target :: x

    ! cp = c_loc( x )   !! => T T
    cp = c_null_ptr   !! => F F

    call sub( cp )
end
```

In the above case, the result always seems to be the same between Lines 1 and 2. But if `cp` might be a null pointer, should I use `c_associated()` first to check the status of `cp` and then use `c_f_pointer()` only when  `cp` is guaranteed to be associated (i.e., not null)?

Comment: To my knowledge standard Fortran requires c_loc to be applied to an associated pointer. Thus (if I am correct, which I'm not 100% sure, hence a comment) the results of the above code are implementation defined.

Comment: @IanBush Thanks much, I agree with c_loc and my MWE was a bit strange... (the intent of the code was not clear either). So I've re-created the MWE as above, and hope that the intent (question) is now more clear...

Comment: I wonder whether you want me to 'prove' my answer, or it's simply believable enough to encourage the interested party to look up the details.

Comment: @francescalus I think it is very reasonable that c_f_pointer() should be given only non-null (associated) C-pointers, so it's no problem without "proof" atm :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c_f_pointer` associates a (Fortran) pointer with the target of a C pointer.  It is necessary for the C pointer to *have* a target.

Yes, you should check the association status of the C pointer if there is a possibility it is not associated.

Comment: Thanks! Then I will make sure to check C-pointer first (rather than using associated() later).

Comment: There's no harm using `c_associated` first: you know after `c_f_pointer` the association status (turns out 'always associated').